# Bug Codification on editor Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

I made my code in Gedit Linux and commit the code in a git repository, after this, I had pulled with Egit plugin of Eclipse, using W10.

I don't know why, in eclipse editor show some bugs of codification, as are these examples:

->**ANOTAÃ‡OES**

->**FunÃ§Ã£o**

When I edit and commit by EGit(eclipse), on repository stay the same of eclipse, with this bugs.
Anyone know how to fix these codification bugs in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

It must be the charset encoding that you used.

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace.
At the bottom of the dialog, there is the "Text File Encoding" box. Change it to Other and pick the encoding that you used in Gedit. *UTF-8* should do the trick.

Comment: I change but no effect. I try all the others and no sucess. =/

Comment: Maybe it is the encoding of the project. Project -> Resource. Same box (Text File Encoding). Can you confirm it?